# What are the differences between gnome, gnome-shell and gnome-core?

Tags: gnome

I am running Ubuntu GNOME and apt says that I have `gnome-shell` installed, but not `gnome` or `gnome-core`.

```
$ apt-cache policy gnome
gnome:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:3.8+4ubuntu3
  Version table:
     1:3.8+4ubuntu3 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages

$ apt-cache policy gnome-shell
gnome-shell:
  Installed: 3.10.4-0ubuntu5
  Candidate: 3.10.4-0ubuntu5
  Version table:
 *** 3.10.4-0ubuntu5 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ apt-cache policy gnome-core
gnome-core:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:3.8+4ubuntu3
  Version table:
     1:3.8+4ubuntu3 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages
```

Why does apt say I have not installed gnome, although I'm using GNOME as the desktop environment?

Comment: Kali linux is off-topic on Ask Ubuntu (hence Aditya's kind edit). We can give you an Ubuntu centric answer, but if you want a Kali centric one please ask on [unix.se]. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is just an issue of metapackages. The Debian world (and I believe the RedHat one as well) has collected certain programs that are used together into easy-to-install [metapackages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages). So, the package `gnome` is actually a shortcut for installing [all sorts of goodies](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/gnome):

> aisleriot, alacarte, avahi-daemon, cheese, cups-pk-helper, desktop-base, evolution, evolution-plugins, file-roller, gedit, gedit-plugins, gimp, gnome-applets, gnome-color-manager, gnome-core, gnome-documents, gnome-games, gnome-media, gnome-nettool, gnome-orca, gnome-shell-extensions, gnome-tweak-tool, gstreamer1.0-libav, gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly, hamster-applet, inkscape, libgtk2-perl, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-gnome, libreoffice-impress, libreoffice-writer, nautilus-sendto, network-manager-gnome, rhythmbox, rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder, rhythmbox-plugins, rygel-playbin, rygel-preferences, rygel-tracker, seahorse, shotwell, simple-scan, sound-juicer, telepathy-gabble, telepathy-rakia, telepathy-salut, tomboy, totem, totem-plugins, tracker-gui, transmission-gtk, vinagre, xdg-user-dirs-gtk, browser-plugin-gnash, gdebi, nautilus-sendto-empathy, telepathy-idle, dia-gnome, gnome-boxes, gnucash, libreoffice-evolution, planner

This is the full Gnome desktop and is not needed to run the Gnome desktop environment. So, while you have `gnome-shell` installed, you don't have all the associated applications like games and email client etc that come with the full desktop environment.

This is not a problem and it does not hinder you from using Gnome in any way.

`gnome-core` [is also a meta package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/gnome-core), it will install the official "core" modules of the Gnome desktop:

> at-spi2-core, baobab, brasero, caribou, caribou-antler, dconf-gsettings-backend, dconf-tools, empathy, eog, evince, evolution-data-server, firefox, or, fonts-cantarell, gconf2, gdm, gkbd-capplet, glib-networking, gnome-backgrounds, gnome-bluetooth, gnome-calculator, gnome-contacts, gnome-control-center, gnome-dictionary, gnome-disk-utility, gnome-font-viewer, gnome-icon-theme, gnome-icon-theme-extras, gnome-icon-theme-symbolic, gnome-keyring, gnome-menus, gnome-online-accounts, gnome-packagekit, gnome-panel, gnome-power-manager, gnome-screensaver, gnome-screenshot, gnome-session, gnome-settings-daemon, gnome-shell, gnome-sushi, gnome-system-log, gnome-system-monitor, gnome-terminal, gnome-themes-standard, gnome-user-guide, gnome-user-share, gsettings-desktop-schemas, gstreamer1.0-plugins-base, gstreamer1.0-plugins-good, gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio, gtk2-engines, gucharmap, gvfs-backends, gvfs-bin, libatk-adaptor, libcanberra-pulse, libcaribou-gtk-module, libcaribou-gtk3-module, libgtk-3-common, libpam-gnome-keyring, metacity, mousetweaks, nautilus, notification-daemon, pulseaudio, sound-theme-freedesktop, tracker-gui, vino, yelp, zenity, network-manager-gnome, gnome,

Note that the `gnome` metapackage also installs the `gnome-core` metapackage. In any case, the main point here is that metapackages are not needed. You can install each of their component packages manually so lacking one or more metapackages does not imply that anything is actually missing from your system.